# IMP-00098 ошибка импорта Oracle

Tags: oracle

Бэкап создавался на Oracle 10g под управлением ОС Win serv 2003, переносится на 11g2 под управлением CentOS7, файл весит 58гб., часть таблиц импортировалась,еще часть осталась не импортированной, потому как данная ошибка появилась при импорте таблицы в 342м строк. Как продолжить импорт таблицы?

Comment: Все еще актуально

Comment: Если к вас есть доступ к My Oracle Support (MOS) посмотрите: __Doc ID 578616.1__